# I am not able to display the data obtained from Firebase Realtime Database on the screen in React Native using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks

I started using Hooks in React Native recently and I'm trying to get the data from Firebase Realtime Database and render it in a FlatList. The data is being displayed on the console with console.log, in the form of an array of objects, but is not being rendered on the screen. what am I doing wrong? How do I make it work correctly?

My code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/database';

export default function QuestList({ navigation }) {
    const title = navigation.getParam('title');

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
          const db = firebase.database();
          db.ref('/questionnaires/')
            .on('value', snapshot => {
              
              //const response = snapshot.val();
              //console.log('value', snapshot.val());
              const response = snapshot.val();
              //console.log(response);
              const keys = Object.keys(response);
              const questWithKeys = keys.map(id => {
              return { ...response[id], id }
              });
              setData(questWithKeys);
              console.log(questWithKeys); 
              //return { data: questWithKeys };
                  
            
            });
        
      }, []);

    /*async() => {
        useEffect(() => {
            const db = firebase.database();
            db.ref('/questionnaires/')
            .on('value', snapshot => {
              console.log(snapshot.val());
            });
        });
    }*/

    

    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 10}}>{data.title}</Text>
        <FlatList
        
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                <View index={index}>
                    <Text >{item.title}</Text>
                </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            numColumns={2}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Don't repost the same problem multiple times please. At best it will be closed, but it may get you banned form Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with the Realtime Database. I had to run the snapshots received through a foreach loop, pushing each snapshot.val() to a new array. I'm not sure why this fixed it, but it has worked for me.

Comment: Firebase saves all data within an object instead of an array. FlatList needs an array to render the data. Foreach does that and the map does that too. That's why Object.keys and the map over there. But I am unable to render them on the screen for some reason

Comment: Have you tried logging the item in the renderItem function?